Setting up firebase functions with Python errors and issues
Can anybody explain how correctly to set up firebase-functions with Python? (building in googles "project IDX")
My current steps:

create "blank workspace"

run firebase init functions-> that create "functions" folder as it should but no "venv" is created (and because of that no dependencies are installed) -> not case for the guy in this video

cd functions -> python3 -m venv venv -> pick "python3" in list (as sugest by gemini) -> instalation completed

adding "pkgs.python3" to dev.nix -> packeges

test runing firebase init again to install missing dependecies (now when I have venv in functions) but getting error: Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (24.0)
/bin/sh: line 1: python3.12: command not found

so bc of that I go to dev.nix and change in packages from  "pkgs.python3" to  "pkgs.python312" (keep in mind that docs says that python 3.10 and 3.11 are supported but only that can fix the issue)

run firebase init again and only now all the dependecies are installed

I can now deploy functions as well
BUT let's say that I want to add numpy library to project:

when in "/functions" directory : source venv/bin/activate

pip install numpy -> python311Packages.pip

import numpy to the project, ex:


from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
import numpy as np

initialize_app()

https_fn.on_request()
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    np.random.seed(42)
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")


run firebase deploy, now I get this error (because I changed to python312 in packages?):


[2024-06-16 11:54:11,957] ERROR in app: Exception on /__/functions.yaml [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py", line 122, in get_functions_yaml
functions = get_functions()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py", line 40, in get_functions
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
File "", line 995, in exec_module
File "", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/user/zzz/functions/main.py", line 7, in 
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2024 11:54:11] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2024 11:54:11] "GET /__/quitquitquit HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error


Can you try using sudo apt install python3-numpy as suggested here
